# Listview not showing consistent data android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to parse [this JSON response](http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/) onto a ListView in android where I am trying to modify the listview by showing an image depending upon the gender and adding a button for male records.

The logic is working fine, except for the last two entries.John Wayne & Leonardo Dicaprio are having details button, same is expected for Johnny Depp & Ravi Tambda.Please guide me for the same.

Using this code, I am trying to differentiate them according to the genders

```
 if(rowData.mgender.equalsIgnoreCase("male"))
                {
                    imageViewStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.male);
                }
    else{
                    imageViewStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.female);
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
```

[image: My output]

**EDIT 1**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            TextView title = null;
            TextView detail = null;
            TextView data=null;
            TextView message=null;

            ImageView imageViewStatus=null;
            Button button=null;

            final RowData rowData= getItem(position);
            if(null == convertView)

            {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.record, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            button=(Button)holder.getProceedButton();


            message=holder.getEmail();
            message.setText(rowData.mEmail);

            title = holder.getName();
            title.setText(rowData.mName);

            detail = holder.getAddress();
            detail.setText(rowData.mAdress);                                                    

            data= holder.getPhoneNumber();
            data.setText(rowData.mMobile+" "+rowData.mOffice);

            imageViewStatus=holder.getImage();

            System.out.println("This is the gender "+rowData.mgender);
            if(rowData.mgender.equalsIgnoreCase("male"))
            {
                imageViewStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.male);
}

            else{
                imageViewStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.female);
                System.out.println("Button Visibility"+button.getVisibility());

                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: Before if condition just log (print) the `rowData.mgender`

Comment: It is giving me response as male, button button is not appearing.

Comment: Please include the whole getView() method in your question, you're probably making mistakes while reusing views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that ListView children are always reused while you scroll them. When you set a property according to some condition in `getView()`, you have to revert that property when the condition isn't met. You're hiding the button when the gender is female, but when this view gets reused to populate a male contact, the button is still invisible and you have to set it as visible again.

Check this out:

```
if(rowData.mgender.equalsIgnoreCase("male"))
{
    imageViewStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.male);
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // You need to add this line in your code
} else {
    imageViewStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.female);
    button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Ok. will try this. I have added getView method also.